# Emberjs Deep Model Associations not available in templates

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, frameworks, associations

I'm new to Emberjs, and I'm trying to get my head around how to get data out of my model.

Here's the data structure as its being returned from my server

```
candidate: {
    image: [image],
    user: {
         name: [User Name]
    }, 
    agent: {
        phone: [phone]
        team: {
            name: [Team Name]
        }
        user: {
            name: [User Name]
        }
    }
}
```

I cant get ember to recognize any associations more than one level deep.

heres my candidate controller

```
App.CandidateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   location: function() {
        var address = this.get('address');
        var city = this.get('city');
        var state = this.get('state');
        var zip = this.get('zip');
        return address + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + ', ' + zip;
    }.property('address', 'city', 'state', 'zip')
});

App.CandidateSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
        agent: {embedded: 'always'},
        user: {embedded: 'always'}
    }
});
```

This allows me to get one level deep, but I need two or three levels of association.

Is there a different way to go about it?

I thought organizing everything on the server the way I want it displayed, and just returning the data as its supposed to be rendered to ember, but I have a feeling I'll run into problems when trying to update the models.

Any help is appreciated.

/******  UPDATE *******/

I have refactored my code and I am now returning data from the serializer like this:

```
{
    candidate: {
        // relevant fields
    },
    agent: {
        //relevant fields
    },
    team: {
        // relevant fields
    }
    user: [
        {  //  candidate user fields    },
        {  //  agent user fields    }
    ]
};
```

However, data is still not available in my template. In the Ember chrome extension, in the data tab, I get

```
candidate: (1)
agent: (0)
team: (0)
user (2)
```

I can see candidate and user data, but not agent or team data.  In my candidate model, I have:

```
App.Candidate = DS.Model.extend({
    // other fields
    user_id: DS.attr('number'),
    agent_id: DS.attr('number'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    agent: DS.belongsTo('agent')
});
```

It doesn't seem like the belongsTo association actually does anything.

So the first issue is that I'm not getting the correct data, the second issue, and the one that makes me think I am going about this incorrectly, is that I have two users information that I need to display in the template.  The first is user information associated with the candidate, and the second is user information that is associated with the agent.  Both data need to appear in the same template.  Since there is no hierarchy to the data, how would the template know which user info to display in each location?

Again, I think Im thinking about this whole thing incorrectly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ember data expects models in a JSON response to be flat, and it's the job of the Serializer to transform your server response into that format. Associations usually are done by ids. The second level is not working because Ember needs to turn each level into an `Ember.Object` in order to observe property changes.

It might help to look over the [JSON conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_json-conventions) portion of the guides. You can also plug your models into the [ember data model maker](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/) and see what your responses should look like. Finally, make sure you're using the [ember-inspector Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en). When I am debugging ember-data related issues, it's usually easiest to just stop after the `model` hook returns, look in the inspector's store tab, and examine what data has been loaded.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks.  I refactored my code based on your suggestions and provided links, but Im still no receiving correct data in my template, please see edit to my question above.  Thanks for your help.